# Can set string variable to Call function without "tel :" in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to the android developing.
i want to add call function to the string variable like this?

```
TextView c = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.email);
String playerChanged = c.getText().toString();
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + playerChanged ));
startActivity(call);
```

here c came by SingleList item.
helpme.

Comment: are you sure you are getting the correct value (a phone number) from c? It looks like c is your email field.

Comment: what kind of exception are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Then start the call intent like so:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-make-phone-call-your-application

Also might want to double-check your `playerChanged` value to make sure it is in fact a phone number, it looks like you are getting that value from a field named "email".

Comment: playerChanged value is a 123456789.but not like this tel:123456789.But im hoping to add this playerChanged value to the callIntent.setData(Uri.parse) this funtion.